# How can I clear the buffer so this works?

Tags: java

It works in the IF statement, but in the ELSE statement, I have to type 4 responses before it prints out. Any ideas? I know I need to clear the buffer somehow I think.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play a game? (Y/N)");
        if(scanInput.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")||scanInput.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

        System.out.println("let's play");
    }

    else if (scanInput.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n") || scanInput.next().equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read from the `InputStream` once:

```
String query = scanInput.next();
if (query.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.out.println("let's play");
} else if (query.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) 
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
} // handle case where not Y or N ...
```

Notice, there's no need to for multiple `String#equalsIgnoreCase` expressions. Also `scanInput.nextLine()` *may* be preferrable here to consume the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling the `next()` method of the scanner four times. Also, the point of `equalsIgnoreCase()` is that you do not need to test for both `y` and `Y`.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play a game? (Y/N)");
String x = scanInput.next();
if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.out.println("let's play");
}
else if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))    
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
```